# How to use Array.filter

Tags: javascript

If I have a structure

```
{
    "users": {
        "John": [1 , 4, 5],
        "Max": [2, 3, 7],
        "Bill": [3, 5, 4]
    }
}
```

array is months arrears for 3 months. I need to print who is most of all owed by month. Example

- Bill, Max, John - for the 1st month.
- Bill, John, Max - for the 2nd month.
- and so on.

I need to do it with JS. Is there any simple way to use Array.filter?

Comment: Why would you want to? That isn't what `filter` is for, this isn't a problem which is well suited to it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var users = 
    [
        {name: "John", values: [1 , 4, 5]},
        {name: "Max", values: [2, 3, 7]},
        {name : "Bill", values: [3, 5, 4]}
    ]
function sortByMonth(monthNumber) {
  return users.sort(function(a, b) { return b.values[monthNumber] - a.values[monthNumber];});
  }
```

This should be what you're looking for, you have to actually change your values into an array but then you can sort by amount owed per month with the sortByMonth function.

Comment: and I can't modify structure.

Comment: What browser are you using? I tested this out in Chrome and passing in 0 (for the first month) returns the array in the order Bill, Max, John like in your example.